# node.js shell command execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am still trying to grasp the finer points of how I can run a linux or windows shell command and capture output within node.js; ultimately, I want to do something like this...

```
//pseudocode
output = run_command(cmd, args)
```

The important piece is that `output` must be available to a globally scoped variable (or object).  I tried the following function, but for some reason, I get `undefined` printed to the console...

```js
function run_cmd(cmd, args, cb) {
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
  var child = spawn(cmd, args);
  var me = this;
  child.stdout.on('data', function(me, data) {
    cb(me, data);
  });
}
foo = new run_cmd('dir', ['/B'], function (me, data){me.stdout=data;});
console.log(foo.stdout);  // yields "undefined" <------
```

I'm having trouble understanding where the code breaks above... a very simple prototype of that model works...

```js
function try_this(cmd, cb) {
  var me = this;
  cb(me, cmd)
}
bar = new try_this('guacamole', function (me, cmd){me.output=cmd;})
console.log(bar.output); // yields "guacamole" <----
```

Can someone help me understand why `try_this()` works, and `run_cmd()` does not?  FWIW, I need to use [`child_process.spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), because [`child_process.exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) has a 200KB buffer limit.

### Final Resolution

I'm accepting James White's answer, but this is the exact code that worked for me...

```
function cmd_exec(cmd, args, cb_stdout, cb_end) {
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn(cmd, args),
    me = this;
  me.exit = 0;  // Send a cb to set 1 when cmd exits
  me.stdout = "";
  child.stdout.on('data', function (data) { cb_stdout(me, data) });
  child.stdout.on('end', function () { cb_end(me) });
}
foo = new cmd_exec('netstat', ['-rn'], 
  function (me, data) {me.stdout += data.toString();},
  function (me) {me.exit = 1;}
);
function log_console() {
  console.log(foo.stdout);
}
setTimeout(
  // wait 0.25 seconds and print the output
  log_console,
250);
```

Comment: In the Final Resolution you should set `me.stdout = "";` in `cmd_exec()` to prevent concatenating `undefined` to the beginning of the result.

Comment: Hey, that final resolution code is completely awful, what if it takes longer than 0.25 second to execute your netstat?

Comment: Ummmm... maybe use one of the answers that I awarded a bonus to?????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute and get the output of a shell command in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/execute-and-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There are three issues here that need to be fixed:

**First** is that you are expecting synchronous behavior while using stdout asynchronously. All of the calls in your `run_cmd` function are asynchronous, so it will spawn the child process and return immediately regardless of whether some, all, or none of the data has been read off of stdout. As such, when you run

```
console.log(foo.stdout);
```

you get whatever happens to be stored in foo.stdout at the moment, and there's no guarantee what that will be because your child process might still be running.

**Second** is that stdout is a [readable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream), so 1) the data event can be called multiple times, and 2) the callback is given a buffer, not a string. Easy to remedy; just change

```
foo = new run_cmd(
    'netstat.exe', ['-an'], function (me, data){me.stdout=data;}
);
```

into

```
foo = new run_cmd(
    'netstat.exe', ['-an'], function (me, buffer){me.stdout+=buffer.toString();}
);
```

so that we convert our buffer into a string and append that string to our stdout variable.

**Third** is that you can only know you've received all output when you get the 'end' event, which means we need another listener and callback:

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, cb, end) {
    // ...
    child.stdout.on('end', end);
}
```

So, your final result is this:

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, cb, end) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        child = spawn(cmd, args),
        me = this;
    child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { cb(me, buffer) });
    child.stdout.on('end', end);
}

// Run C:\Windows\System32\netstat.exe -an
var foo = new run_cmd(
    'netstat.exe', ['-an'],
    function (me, buffer) { me.stdout += buffer.toString() },
    function () { console.log(foo.stdout) }
);
```

Comment: "there's no guarantee what that will be because your child process might still be running" close...but there is a guarantee that it will *not* be set at that point in time, and will only be set when the callback is finally called, as you indicated elsewhere

Comment: This is an excellent answer with great explanations of some very important JS concepts. Nice!

Comment: You'll want to do `this.stdout = "";` inside the `run()` function, otherwise your `console.log(foo.sdtout);` will be prefixed with `undefined`.

Answer (score 79):

A simplified version of the accepted answer (third point), just worked for me.

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, callBack ) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var child = spawn(cmd, args);
    var resp = "";

    child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { resp += buffer.toString() });
    child.stdout.on('end', function() { callBack (resp) });
} // ()
```

Usage:

```
run_cmd( "ls", ["-l"], function(text) { console.log (text) });

run_cmd( "hostname", [], function(text) { console.log (text) });
```

Comment: What about the return value, when the process return a non zero, how can I get it?

Comment: `child.stdout.on('close', (errCode) => { console.log(errCode) } )`

Answer (score 52):

I used this more concisely :

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ls -la", puts);
```

it works perfectly. :)

Comment: This works well, and does not require any additional node modules.  I like it!

Comment: `sys.puts()` was deprecated in 2011 (with Node.js v0.2.3). You should use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: that actually works... so I'm wondering, why isn't this the answer? it's so simple

Comment: Wow!! this answer is perfect and elegant. thank you.

Answer (score 45):

Simplest way is to just use the ShellJS lib ...

```
$ npm install [-g] shelljs
```

EXEC Example:

```
require('shelljs/global');

// Sync call to exec()
var version = exec('node --version', {silent:true}).output;

// Async call to exec()
exec('netstat.exe -an', function(status, output) {
  console.log('Exit status:', status);
  console.log('Program output:', output);
});
```

[ShellJs.org](http://shelljs.org) supports many common shell commands mapped as NodeJS functions including:

- **cat**
- **cd**
- **chmod**
- **cp**
- **dirs**
- **echo**
- **exec**
- **exit**
- **find**
- **grep**
- **ln**
- **ls**
- **mkdir**
- **mv**
- **popd**
- **pushd**
- **pwd**
- **rm**
- **sed**
- **test**
- **which**

Comment: how to add a parameter to the shell script called by shell.exec("foo.sh") ?

Comment: You can just append your arguments top the string: `shell.exec("foo.sh arg1 arg2 ... ")`.  Your `foo.sh` script can reference these using `$1`, `$2` ... etc.

Comment: If the command you're trying to execute is going to need input from user then DON'T use ShellJS exec(). This function is not interactive in nature, as it'll just take command and print output, Can't accept inputs in between. Use built in child_process instead. E.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104898/9749509](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104898/9749509)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I ended up writing a node extension for this. You can check out the git repository. It's open source and free and all that good stuff !

https://github.com/aponxi/npm-execxi

> ExecXI is a node extension written in C++ to execute shell commands
>   one by one, outputting the command's output to the console in
>   real-time. Optional chained, and unchained ways are present; meaning
>   that you can choose to stop the script after a command fails
>   (chained), or you can continue as if nothing has happened !

Usage instructions are in the [ReadMe file](https://github.com/aponxi/npm-execxi/blob/master/README.md). Feel free to make pull requests or submit issues!

I thought it was worth to mention it.

Answer (score 4):

@TonyO'Hagan is comprehrensive `shelljs` answer, but, I would like to highlight the synchronous version of his answer:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var output = shell.exec('netstat -rn', {silent:true}).output;
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Synchronous one-liner:

```
require('child_process').execSync("echo 'hi'", function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a variable conflict in your `run_cmd` function:

```
  var me = this;
  child.stdout.on('data', function(me, data) {
    // me is overriden by function argument
    cb(me, data);
  });
```

Simply change it to this:

```
  var me = this;
  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    // One argument only!
    cb(me, data);
  });
```

In order to see errors always add this:

```
  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log( data );
  });
```

**EDIT** You're code fails because you are trying to run `dir` which is **not** provided as a separate standalone program. It is a command in `cmd` process. If you want to play with filesystem use native `require( 'fs' )`.

Alternatively ( which I do not recommend ) you can create a batch file which you can then run. Note that OS by default fires batch files via `cmd`.

Comment: thank you for your help... however, even when I run `C:\Windows\System32\netstat.exe`, this still does not yield results... My exact syntax was `foo = new run_cmd('netstat.exe', ['-an'], function (me, data){me.stdout=data;});`... I also tried the full path with no success so far

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually returning anything from your run_cmd function.

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, done) {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var child = spawn(cmd, args);
    var result = { stdout: "" };
    child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
            result.stdout += data;
    });
    child.stdout.on("end", function () {
            done();
    });
    return result;
}

> foo = run_cmd("ls", ["-al"], function () { console.log("done!"); });
{ stdout: '' }
done!
> foo.stdout
'total 28520...'
```

Works just fine. :)

Comment: I don't think `return` is required as long as you properly set the object attributes

Answer (score 0):

A promisified version of the most-awarded answer:

```
  runCmd: (cmd, args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
      var child = spawn(cmd, args)
      var resp = ''
      child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { resp += buffer.toString() })
      child.stdout.on('end', function () { resolve(resp) })
    })
  }
```

To use:

```
 runCmd('ls').then(ret => console.log(ret))
```