# How to delete and insert with a single command in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

So, I have a collection like this:

```
[{
   "name":String,
   "address":String,
   "hobby":Array of Strings
}...]
```

Every hour I query an API and get the response like so:

```
[{
   "name":String,
   "address":String,
   "hobby":Array of Strings
}...]
```

Exactly the same.
What I wish to accomplish is, I want to remove all the values from the collection and add all these new values that I am getting from the API response.
I can do, delete and insert, but, its a production app and I have noticed that sometimes deletion fails and sometimes insertion fails. I am not able to find the right query to update the db.

This is exactly what I want:

```
Update the database with new values (Array of objects) every hour while not giving a single damn about the existing values.
```

The code is written with mongoose in NodeJS. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: why don't you use one of the available update methods? You can update the content using one of them every hour.

Comment: Which query would lead to me updating everything in the db irregardless of existing values? @AbdurrahimAhmadov

Comment: if I understood correctly, do you want to update the collection with new data and set the fields as `'  '`  with the data that are not given?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb has [a set of command line tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/) that you could use for this for example, using mongoimport to import (and drop all existing data)

```sh
mongoimport --collection=yourcollection --drop --db=databaseName "connectionURI" filename.json
```

[Executing mongoimport inside code with Javascript/Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436900/executing-mongoimport-inside-code-with-javascript-node-js)

Though this still isn't ideal. Does the API you're scraping not have any kind of unique identifier for these elements?

It'd be much better to use that ID to [replace](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) the documents directly via code, and then perform a separate query to find all IDs that are not in the database but not in the list you got from the API, then delete them