# Node.js: Writing a function to return spawn stdout as a string

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to return the output of this function as a string, but it keeps returning as undefined. Where am I going wrong?

```
function run(cmd){
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var command = spawn(cmd);
    var result = '';
    command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            result += data.toString();
    });
    command.on('close', function(code) {
            return result;
    });
}
console.log(run('ls'));
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your function returns immediately after `command.on` statement. The `return` statement in your callback for the `close` event is returned to nowhere. The `return` belongs to event callback, not to `run()`.

Put `console.log` call instead of `return result`.

Generally speaking you should write something like:

```
function run(cmd, callback) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var command = spawn(cmd);
    var result = '';
    command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
         result += data.toString();
    });
    command.on('close', function(code) {
        return callback(result);
    });
}

run("ls", function(result) { console.log(result) });
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I change it to have the function output to a variable instead of console.log?

Comment: You should do whatever you have to do with command result in callback function, just replace console.log with real code. Everything is asynchronous, so even if you try to put result value in a global variable you can't tell when it'll be available. If you really want to do something in non-async way this could help: https://github.com/caolan/async#series. But ask yourself why you want to do that.

Comment: Waaaah I'm so silly. Was resolving my promises on `child.stdout.on('data', data)` and wondering why my output was incomplete and randomly truncated. If you're experiencing that problem store the data into a variable first which is resolved/rejected inside your `child.on('close')` event as in this answer. Thanks @fuwaneko

Answer (score 5):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    command  = spawn('ls', ['/tmp/']);
command.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution) is exactly the same question as yours.

Comment: clever, but he probably wants to do moer then just print the result to process.stdout

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I store stdout.pipe into a variable?

Answer (score 5):

You can always wrap your function in a promise and return that. I find more efficient than @fuwaneko's callback solution

```
function run(cmd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var command = spawn(cmd)
        var result = ''
        command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
             result += data.toString()
        })
        command.on('close', function(code) {
            resolve(result)
        })
        command.on('error', function(err) { reject(err) })
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution while working with the `ping` command and it didn't work. @fuwaneko's solution worked for me, however.

Answer (score 0):

clean way is using `async/await` so try like this:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;
 
try {
    const child = spawn(cmd)
    return { stdout: child.stdout.toString(), stderr: child.stderr.toString() }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error
}
```

Comment: and where is `async/await`?

Comment: @srghma in the first line of code I required spawnSync then do not need to using async/await

Answer (score 0):

Typescript version:
(following common current async usage)

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'

const run = (commandLine: string) => new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
  const [command, ...args] = commandLine.split(/\s+/)
  const child = spawn(command, args)
  const output = [] as string[]
  child.stdout.on('data', chunk => output.push(chunk))
  child.on('close', () => resolve(output.join('').trim()))
  child.on('error', error => reject(error))
})
```

usage:

```
const branch = await run('git branch --show-current')
```