# Cross distribution terminal opening

Tags: node.js, terminal, electron, spawn, xterm

In electron, I am registering a shortcut to open a terminal:

```
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Alt+Shift+P', () => {
    spawn(os.platform() === 'linux' ? 'xterm' : 'cmd');
});
```

I noticed that `xterm` don't have the same "style" of the terminal opened from OS menu and I found that the latter is customized by the Desktop Environment (I have an Ubuntu Mate where its terminal is `mate-terminal` and a RedHat 7.5 with `konsole`).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407656/how-to-distinguish-between-different-operating-system-distros-in-node-js) that nodejs don't have an API to detect the distribution, so it seems not feasible to know which terminal to run depending on distribution.

Is there any way to open the correct terminal or to style `xterm` as the OS one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** There's no standardised API for that and you cannot be sure that a distribution indicates the terminal application.

First of all, XTerm, Mate's Terminal, Konsole, etc. are all different applications. And because Ubuntu Mate under the hood reports as Ubuntu, AFAIK, you cannot even be certain that this is the application registered as "the" terminal app. Also, nearly every desktop environment brings its own terminal application, and since you can install multiple terminal applications side by side, it is at most an educated guess to automatically select an "appropriate" terminal application.

However, there are multiple approaches which can be considered to solve this (aesthetic) problem:

1. *Let the user decide what terminal application they want.* If your application has a configuration file, you could use that to write a value specified by the user and take that as the terminal app. In theory, they could specify a path to an application which is not a terminal app, but then it's their fault.
2. *Compile a list of known terminal applications and check if they're installed.* For example, you could make an (ordered) list of the apps your application should search for and if none of them is found, fall back to XTerm (because that is installed on most if not all desktop systems running Linux). To see if an application is installed and runnable on Linux, you can use the `which` command. Example:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require ("child_process");
const terms = [ "konsole", "mate-terminal", "gnome-terminal" /* ... */ ];
var terminal = null;

// In your startup method (e.g. before opening a BrowserWindow)
if (os.platform () === "linux") {
    for (term in terms) {
        which = spawnSync ("which", [term]);
        if (which.status !== null && which.status === 0) { // Command found
            terminal = term;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (terminal === null) terminal = "xterm";
} else {
    terminal = "cmd";
}
```

Of course you could also use `spawn` in favour of `spawnSync` but this will get more complex. Also, this only provides you with the first application found to be installed, it does not select the one "appropriate" for the desktop environment. But I believe it is a good step in the right direction if you want your application the be (somewhat) seemlessly integrated into the DE.

As a side note, your code does not take MacOS into account, but it is also possible to open a terminal on MacOS, it's simply called "Terminal" there.

Comment: Thank you for the wide answer. I have already thought about your first choice and I think I will go with it.

Answer (score 0):

*Node.js* doesn't provide a method to detect the name of the distribution natively, because there is no standard way to get that information from different *Linux* distributions.

But you can do it with a library sush as [getos](https://github.com/retrohacker/getos):

```
const getos = require('getos');

getos((err, os) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(os.dist, os.codename)
})
```

Comment: I tried that module, but it cannot detect the Desktop Environment: it can distinguish Ubuntu and Redhat but it does not tell me if those OS uses KDE or Mate or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [OpenTerm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-term), it has configurable function which automatically determines terminal to use, and it currently supports windows and linux, but not MacOs.

```js
const { VTexec } = require('open-term')
VTexec('help') // Runs "help" command in determined terminal.
```

"*help*" command would work both on **bash** and **cmd**. So i use it here as example.