# Calling shell command form javascript form browser

Tags: javascript, html, shell

I am trying to run some command on the client system through server. I know server has lots of security issues while executing server commands, is there any way to run command form browser.

I have following commands in nodejs but, i need this to run form the browser in clients system.

same as in this question but form html page.
[node.js shell command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution)

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, callBack ) {
   var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   var child = spawn(cmd, args);
   var resp = "";      
   child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { resp += buffer.toString() });
   child.stdout.on('end', function() { callBack (resp) });
}
```

Usage:

```
run_cmd( "ls", ["-l"], function(text) { console.log (text) });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you may not execute arbitrary shell/console commands through a browser.

The security implications for this would be gigantic. You wouldn't want someone to execute:

```
run_cmd( "rm", ["-rf *"], function(text) { console.log ("lol") });
```

Through your browser. Not even if you could explicitly trust it.

Comment: Isn't there any way to accomplish such task?

Comment: Is there any way to open a program that is installed on client machine from HTML page through javascript. This will also sove my problem.

Comment: Not through Javascript, no. If you have control of that client machine, you could write a piece of software and use [protocol handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers) to launch that software. It can then redirect the request to the console on behalf of the user.