# Synchronous child process calls for shell scripting (including CLI) in Node.js 0.10.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, popen, command-line-interface

Synchronous child process calls [are now available](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-execsync-a-synchronous-api-for-child-processes/) in the versions of Node.js that are under development (i.e. unstable). This is great news for writing shell scripts, as it will allow code like this:

```
var history = child_process.execSync('git log', { encoding: 'utf8' });
process.stdout.write(history);
```

However, for code aimed at the current stable version of Node.js (v0.10.30), synchronous child process calls are [not available](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.30/api/child_process.html) except via external  libraries. The two most popular such libraries appear to be [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/shelljs) and [exec-sync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec-sync).

*For shell scripts intended for use with v0.10.x, and which must call binaries or other executables and process their output, what are the relative pros and cons of these two libraries or other comparable libraries? Please provide code samples for illustration, if appropriate.*

Comment: While it's a well-written question, this will probably be closed as too opinion-based :-/

Comment: Thanks. I hope it won't be closed, as it seems perfectly appropriate: essentially a refinement of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14458508/82216) . However, do say if you think I should flag it for migration to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or similar

Comment: Hm, I don't know whether it's [on-topic there](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) either.

Comment: Well, I'm not asking for opinions, I'm asking for concrete advantages/disadvantages to two precisely specified alternative programming strategies (in this case, using one library vs using another, for the same task). This sort of question has been asked and answered on SO for years. In any case, there's room for [inclusionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Inclusion) on SO/SE :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at three options: the two mentioned in the question, plus [execsync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/execsync).

### [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/shelljs)

`shelljs` is much more than a library for calling child processes. Primarily, it is a cross-platform JavaScript implementation of several POSIX utilities and shell builtins: `>`, `cat`, `cd`, `chmod`, `cp`, `dirs`, `echo`, `env`, `exec`, `exit`, `find`, `grep`, `ln`, `ls`, `mkdir`, `mv`, `popd`, `pushd`, `pwd`, `rm`, `sed`, `test`, `which`. It also provides a couple of useful functions of its own: `error()` and `tempdir()`.

Its `exec` function can be used to run an external executable synchronously.

#### Syntax example

Using global namespace:

```
require('shelljs/global');
var version = exec('node --version', {silent:true}).output;
console.log('version ' + version);
```

Alternatively, using local namespace:

```
var sh = require('shelljs');
var version = sh.exec('node --version', {silent:true}).output;
console.log('version ' + version);
```

#### Key stats/specs

- Dependencies: 0
- Dependents: 411
- Downloads this month: 957851
- License: BSD*

#### Pros

- No dependencies.
- Can be used via global or local namespace at developer's discretion.
- Huge number of dependent packages and users, so likely to remain in use for some time.

#### Cons

- Cannot distinguish a called executable's output to stderr from its output to stdout. [Bug](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs/issues/92)?
- The shelljs documentation [warns](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs/blob/b8e1507b8db9668219435bdff5a06f06483e7636/README.md), "For long-lived processes, it's best to run exec() asynchronously as the current synchronous implementation uses a lot of CPU. This should be getting fixed soon."

### [exec-sync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec-sync) / [execSync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/execSync)

[exec-sync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec-sync) has been [retired](https://github.com/jeremyfa/node-exec-sync) in favour of [execSync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/execSync). The rest of this section therefore refers to the latter.

The execSync library consists of a JavaScript wrapper around a C++ core. During the installation of execSync, the C++ core is compiled into a platform-appropriate NodeJS binary module.

#### Syntax example

```
var sh = require('execSync');
var version = sh.exec('node --version').stdout;
console.log('version ' + version);
```

#### Key stats/specs

- Dependencies: 1
- Dependents: 91
- Downloads this month: 20525
- License: MIT

#### Pros

- Straightforward once installed.
- Large number of dependent packages and users, so likely to remain in use for some time.

#### Cons

- Not dependency-free.
- Installation requires the presence of a C++ compiler.
- Cannot distinguish a called executable's output to stderr from its output to stdout. [Bug](https://github.com/mgutz/execSync/issues/23)?

### [execsync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/execsync)

Worth mentioning here as it is easily confused with execSync (see above) by any case-insensitive search engine, other algorithm, or human. Confusing matters further, the author of execsync has used the orthography "execSync" at a few points in execsync's code and documentation.

Like execSync above, the execsync library consists of a JavaScript wrapper around a C++ core. During the installation of execsync, the C++ core is compiled into a platform-appropriate NodeJS binary module.

#### Syntax example

```
var sh = require('execsync');
var version = sh('node --version');
console.log('version ' + version);
```

#### Key stats/specs

- Dependencies: 0
- Dependents: 3
- Downloads this month: 20233
- License: NYSL

#### Pros

- No dependencies.

#### Cons

- Inconsistent internal orthography.
- Installation requires the presence of a C++ compiler.
- Documentation is in Japanese (not a "con" for everyone, admittedly).
- Cannot distinguish a called executable's output to stderr from its output to stdout.
- Small number of dependents, so presumably less entrenched in Node.js community.

Comment: +1 for answering this yourself. You might even remove the specific packages from the question, to make it more open-ended :-)

Comment: Thanks :) I've added the text "or other comparable libraries" to the question.

Comment: why do we need a library to do this, doesnt spawnAsync do it?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, no it doesn't. It is for asynchronous use.