# How does expressjs response shell command execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to setup a site quickly, so I try express now. But I am pretty new to it. ;-(
I need to invoke some executables in server part, and send to result back to browser. Following [node.js shell command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution), now first step is done, but error happens in the second step.

here is my code:

```js
/* GET home page. */
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    // Run C:\Windows\System32\netstat.exe -an
    var foo = new run_cmd(
        'netstat.exe', ['-an'],
        function (me, buffer) {
            me.stdout += buffer.toString()
        },
        function () {
            res.send('netstat done~');
            console.log(foo.stdout)
        }
    );
    //console.log(req);
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});

function run_cmd(cmd, args, cb, end) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        child = spawn(cmd, args),
        me = this;
    child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) {
        cb(me, buffer)
    });
    child.stdout.on('end', end);
}
```

Anyone could help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: GET home page with a POST? That doesn't sound right.