# How to get the error occurred while executing a command using execSync()?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to compile and run a C++ file using execSync(). It works fine when there are no compilation errors. But when a compile time error occurs the output returned by execSync() is an empty buffer. How do I get the error message ?

This is my code:

[image: this is how my code looks like]

This is the returned output that I'm trying to capture:

[image: this is what i want as my returned output]

Comment: I don't know execSync but I'd guess the problem is you're fetching back the stdout output whereas the compiler is reporting errors to stderr.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077917/6942210

Comment: @PhilippKief try catch was not working for me , may be because the child process has done its job perfectly by running the command, exception only occurs either when process times out or has a non-zero exit code. Actually the problem is solved , i just used spawnSync() and accessed the stderr stream.