# How to execute 'npm run' command programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some custom testing script, which I can run with `npm run test` command, which executes some Node script for starting e2e/unit tests. But before it I must start webpack dev server with `npm run dev` (it's a some custom Node script too, details doesn't matter) in other terminal window. So, I want to omit `npm run dev` manually executing and move it to custom `npm run test` script, i.e. I want to execute webpack dev server programmatically in Node script. How can I execute `npm run dev` programmatically using Node script and stop it then?

```
"dev": "node node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --host 0.0.0.0 --history-api-fallback --debug --inline --progress --config config/config.js"
```

Comment: Why not create an `npm start` that runs the other two scripts? Like `"start": "npm run dev & npm run test"`

Comment: @elclanrs  `npm run test` should not start before `npm run dev`

Comment: Why not run `webpack-dev-server` [programmatically](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api)?

Comment: @robertklep - it's a good suggestion, I'll try

Comment: @malcoauri if it doesn't work out, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js/15957574#15957574), which explains how to run NPM programmatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 93):

You can use `execSync` to run npm scripts one by one:

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
    
execSync(`npm run dev'),
execSync('npm run test')
```

Comment: error: expected a function and UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: The UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error is because the series param expects an array of functions. So you can resolve this error by doing ```series([
 () => exec('npm run dev'),
 () => exec('npm run test')
]); ```

Comment: what I got working and what I think is the correct pattern is `(cb) => exec('npm run dev', cb)`

Comment: Just FYI, this relies on an external package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Answer (score 36):

Here is a solution that should work reliably across all platforms. It's also very concise. Put this into `build.js`, then run `node build`.

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process')

execSync("npm run clean")
execSync("npm run minify")
execSync("npm run build_assets")
```

It will immediately abort on abnormal npm termination.

Comment: To show console output with the above method, attach stdio as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104898/5771199

Comment: upvote for this because it doesn't require an external library

Comment: This times out for me... It's close though...

Answer (score 29):

(As @fariz-luqman notes below, this (may) have been removed in npm 8.0.0.)

Just install `npm`:

```
npm install npm
```

Then in your program:

```
npm.commands.run('dev', (err) => { ... });
```

See the source for more info. The `npm.commands` object is an unofficial API for npm. Note that using `exec` or `spawn` to execute `npm` is safer, since the API is unofficial.

Comment: Though there are advantages to @foysal-osmany's answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957529/can-i-install-a-npm-package-from-javascript-running-in-node-js/19406194

Comment: Thats great! I didn't know you could use NPM as a module. Where is the JavaScript API documentation?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation. My answer is based on samples of code from various places.

Comment: Also note that I agree that using `exec` is safer. The reason that I used the `npm` module directly was in order to avoid spinning up a second node.js runtime.

Comment: @Xunnamius, no this is not the correct answer. Please refer to your own link. It is not safe to call npm as a module for several reasons.

Comment: @JulianKnight You're right. Though I don't remember my usecase, I believe I used exec instead. Though I'm curious what you mean by "not safe" and "several reasons"? Do you just mean the size and unstable API?

Comment: The unstable API and the fact that there have previously been issues between specific versions of npm/node.js

Comment: As mentioned above - the API is internal and not safe to use unless you're ready to deal with unannounced breaking changes. I did it to avoid having two separate Node.js runtimes and it worked for me.

Comment: `npm.command` does not exist, exists `npm.commands` console.log(require('npm').command, require('npm').commands)

Comment: Please note that this has been removed since npm v8.0.0

Answer (score 13):

An npm blog post recommends using `shelljs`:

```
let shell = require("shelljs");

shell.exec("echo shell.exec works");
shell.exec("npm run dev");
```

See https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm.html

Comment: This is actually a good answer, it prints out the logs as well.

Comment: That's not npm documentation, it's a blog post with a warning that the blog has been discontinued. Npm is not node, and the node docs cover the `child_process.exec` command: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-exec.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), it is really usefull and easy...

```
npm install pm2
```

```
const pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.start({
    script: 'npm -- run monitorTheWeather',
    autorestart : false 
  }, (err, apps) => {
    pm2.disconnect()
    if (err) { throw err }
  })
```

Comment: Using your code I get the following error: `
C:\givingway\gw-ts\t.js:11
                        throw err
                        ^
[
  Error: Script not found: C:\givingway\gw-ts\npm -- run test`

Answer (score 0):

work for me :

```
import { series } from "async";
import { exec } from "child_process";
series([
    (cb) => {
        exec("commands here", (err, std, stderr) => {
            // your callback here
            return cb(); // series callback here
        });
    },
    (cb) => {
        exec("commands here", (err, std, stderr) => {
            // your callback here
            return cb(); // series callback here
        });
    },
]);
```