# Execute npm script within mocha test

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I currently have a script 'npm run make-file' which will create a boiler plate file. Nothing fancy at all, but I am trying to create a test for that in my test suite. I am using Mocha/Chai for testing.

1. Is it even possible to run a script in the terminal *from a mocha test*?

   ```
   describe('Make File', function () {
     it('Runs npm run make file', function (done) {
          // What would belong here? 
      });
    });
   ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032047/how-to-execute-npm-run-command-programmatically