# How to execute command from node application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to call to CMD command from my node JS application ,
is it possible ?

I try with the following (POC) and I got error

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    function cmd_exec(cmd, args, cb_stdout, cb_end) {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
            child = spawn(cmd, args),
            me = this;
        me.exit = 0;  // Send a cb to set 1 when cmd exits
        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            cb_stdout(me, data)
        });
        child.stdout.on('end', function () {
            cb_end(me)
        });
    }
    foo = new cmd_exec('npm', 'install glob --save',
        function (me, data) {
            me.stdout += data.toString();
        },
        function (me) {
            me.exit = 1;
        }
    );

    setTimeout(
        // wait 0.25 seconds and print the output
        log_console,
        250);


    function log_console() {
        console.log(foo.stdout);
    }
    res.send("Hello world");
});
```

I saw this code in the following link

[node.js shell command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution)

The error is :
TypeError: Incorrect value of args option
in line `child = spawn(cmd, args),`

what am I doing wrong here ?Currnlty I just use the npm install command(just for testing) but any other command that I can execute and run will be sufficient

Comment: clearly `args` contains something it shouldn't. It looks like you gave it a function...

Comment: The command in this case is `node`, the arguments are `install glob --save`

Comment: @KevinB - can You please provide example what I should change as answer and I'll try it ASAP,Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing a terminal command, there are two parts: The command, and the arguments. In your case, the command is `npm`, and the arguments is everything that comes after that.

```
cmd_exec('npm', ['install', 'glob', '--save'],
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried it and I got the same error ,any idea why?Since for first I run it as poc I've just one file which is called server.js and I run it,I've update my question with all the code in the server.js file(this is all my program)

Comment: oops, supposed to be an array.

Comment: Thanks 1+ Kevin Now the error is changed to following, any idea what it can be? events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: No idea. looks unreleated to me.

Comment: I provided in the post all the code which i use in the poc ,ive just one file this exact the same code that I provided and I try to test it...does it run for you ?can you suggest other command which I can use to verify that this is working (other then the npm insatll...) thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok ,assume that I want to try to set env variable node.myenv via this code what should I change to make it work in cmd_exec('npm', ['install', 'glob', '--save'],,thanks! I need somehow to check that this is working and with the previos command i got the error :(, im fairly new to this topic ...

Comment: Setting an env var won't affect the currently running node app, if that's what you're trying to do.