# How to execute "chef-apply script.rb" command in node.js function?

Tags: node.js, windows, chef-infra, exec, spawn

I am using cmd to execute my chef commands, How do i run them using node.js?

```
PS C:\Users\xyz\chef-repo> chef-apply script.rb
```

I want to run this command using node.js

```
exports.testscript=function(req,res){
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
console.log("inside function");
 var child = exec('chef-apply azurepro.rb' ,{cwd: 'C:\Users\anurag.s\chef-repo'},
    function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout); 
    console.log(stderr); 
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(error);
    }
        });

//child.stdin.end();
};
```

this is my code. I am getting this error and my command is .bat file.

```
{ [Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT]
 code: 'ENOENT',
 errno: 'ENOENT',
 syscall: 'spawn cmd.exe',
path: 'cmd.exe',
cmd: 'cmd.exe /s /c "chef-apply azurepro.rb"' }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js shell command execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`child_process.exec` function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). So your call would be like this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec('chef-apply script.rb',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    # Your callback here
});
```

Comment: There is no output after execution of the script. The script I use provisions and bootstraps a VM in azure. It runs fine both in powershell and bash but here there is neither response nor any error message.

Comment: You would have to print out the stdout and/or stderr yourself.