# Open new console to run another Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I'm trying to do is open a new command prompt through Node and run a Javascript file.

For example, I would

```
node file1.js
```

And that would open a new console instance, which would instantly run

```
node file2.js
```

I have the basic outline and can open a new instance, just not pass any commands/arguments

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.execSync('start cmd.exe');
```

I need help passing command line params, cant find out how though.

Comment: Simply write a shell script that calls both of them.

Comment: I want to open a new instance of the console at a certain point during the program, while its running.

Comment: Okay so you are having problems passing command line params ?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution#14510775 . Is this what you are looking for ? If not edit the question to be a little more specific on the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.execSync('start node file2.js');
```

Worked for me. Please make sure node.exe is in your PATH