# Node.js - Set system date / time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, time

Is there a way to set the date/time on the operating system from a node.js server?

There are plenty of examples on how to change the time-zone but i need to change the actual date / time of the PC

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the time?

Comment: @mplungjan how is this a duplicate question? Have you even bothered to read the question you say its a duplicate of?

Comment: The computer that the Node.js server will be running on has to keep in time with other PC's on the network, to within a second or so.

Comment: You want to run a system command from node. The duplicate I posted shows you how. How is it not a duplicate? Did you even look at it? I reopened...

Comment: @mplungjan my apologies, it seems that job would be what i am looking for

Comment: so this IS a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution

Comment: Not exactly, i was asking about setting the system time, the fact that you can do that through a command is negligible as im sure there are a lot of questions that can be answered using a system command.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based of of @Mimouni's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23156354/1799272 on a different question, I just changed the include of sys to util, because of deprecation.

Furthermore due to our implementation and requirements (we start other windows services if the time was wrong) I imported 'node-windows'. However you are welcome to see if you can **elevate** the user without this if you only want to use built in npm features.

basically you have 3 important steps:

1. Convert str/int to the date you want
2. Format the date correctly
3. run the elevated command

Here as follows:

```
const sys = require('util')
const win = require('node-windows')

dateTime    = new Date(time) //Convert string or number to date
let day     = dateTime.getDate() 
let month   = dateTime.getUTCMonth() + 1 
let year    = dateTime.getFullYear() 
let updateD = `${year}-${month}-${day}` //Format the string correctly

//Add a callback function (this can be somewhere else)
function execCallback(error, stdout, stderr) { 
     if (error) {
         console.log(error)
     } else {
         console.log(stdout) 
     }
}
var exec = win.elevate(`cmd /c date ${updateD}`,undefined, execCallback);
```

if you wish to set the time, replace **date** in the exec with **time**.