# How to set server time in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking

I would like to set (mock) my custom time to the Node.js server for testing purposes. Something like this:

```
console.log(new Date());
// Sat Jun 30 2018 20:00:00 GMT+0100
//                 ^^
someFunctionToSetTime('Sat Jun 30 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0100')
//                                     ^^
console.log(new Date());
// Sat Jun 30 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0100
//                 ^^
```

How do I do this?

P.S. I don't really want to fake the `Date` class.

Comment: Sinon's fake timers are nice for this: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.0.1/fake-timers/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089562/node-js-set-system-date-time?

Comment: Why not just use `Date` constructor with parameters? i.e. `var d = new Date(2018,06,30, 12, 00);`

Comment: Because it is about mocking the current user's time. In the real code it just calls `new Date()`, but in the test it needs to return a mocked value.

Answer (score 4):

Just monkey patch the Date constructor:

```
let now = 'Sat Jun 30 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0100';

{
   const oldDate = Date;
   Date = function(...args) {
     if(args.length) {
       return new oldDate(...args);
     } else {
      return new oldDate(now);
    }
  };
  Date.parse = oldDate.parse;
  Date.UTC = oldDate.UTC;
  Date.now = () => +(new Date());
}
```

Comment: This works. But it also seems to remove some aspects of the native `Date` class. For example it removes the `Date.now` function. My project had dependencies which rely on `Date.now`, so this method breaks them

Comment: @defraggled sure, touching such a fundamental class will always break something. This should really only be used for testing purposes. I've added all static methods for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

First option : Without external modules you can use this to get timezone Date and time in node.js
 `var myDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'Europe/Paris'
  });`

Second option : Use [momentjs timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) witch allows you to set your location and more... just check the documentation.

Comment: Timezone will not work since I want to mock, let's say, for the past year.