# Open Terminal and execute CLI commands via JS / NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, ubuntu, terminal

Is there any way/code snippet through which we can open Ubuntu terminal and execute terminal commands through JavaScript / Node.js or any UI based language?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your request? Do you mean that from JavaScript, is there a command to open a terminal window? Or is there a way -- from any language -- to open a terminal window? Or perhaps you mean to run shell commands, without necessarily opening a terminal window?
From Node.js or other programs with access to OS processes, the answer is yes. From JavaScript in the browser, the answer is no.

Comment: So i need to build a UI and based on UI input parameters, I need to run I need to perform terminal based commands/shell commands. Is there a way to perform it?

Comment: Yes: from Node JS you can call shell commands [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution) and [another here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js). The basic idea is to open a new process and run a command in it.

Comment: Thank you for the reference

Answer (score 2):

You can run **any shell command from nodeJs** via the childProcess **native** API (witout installing any dependencies)

### Simple way

```js
var { exec } = require('child_process'); // native in nodeJs

const childProcess = exec('git pull');
```

### Snippet to handle logs and errors

I often have a bunch of cli commands to process, so I've created this simple helper. It handle errors, exit and can be awaited in your scripts to match different scenarios

```js
async function execWaitForOutput(command, execOptions = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const childProcess = exec(command, execOptions);

        // stream process output to console
        childProcess.stderr.on('data', data => console.error(data));
        childProcess.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data));
        // handle exit
        childProcess.on('exit', () => resolve());
        childProcess.on('close', () => resolve());
        // handle errors
        childProcess.on('error', error => reject(error));
    })
}
```

That I can use like:

```js
await execWaitForOutput('git pull');
// then
await execWaitForOutput('git pull origin master');
// ...etc
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to send another command after the first one?

Comment: @HolyRandom yes sure, see the last example

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module - [OpenTerm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-term). It opens new Virtual Terminal in cross platform way and execute command:

```js
const { VTexec } = require('open-term')
VTexec('help') // Runs "help" command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this node module.

https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#examples