# get list of file names from aws s3 using node js wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a code to fetch a file name from s3 that only gives a single file,
for example I have a file's names as 01-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz, 02-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz and so on
but my code print only 01-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz

This my code

```
let items = [];

const listS3Objects = (marker) => {
  s3.listObjects({
    Bucket: 'JobPoy',
    Prefix: 'datacenter/01-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz',
    Marker: marker
  }, (err, s3Items) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      process.exit();
    }
    s3Items.Contents.forEach(i => items.push(i.Key));
    if (s3Items.Contents.length === 1000) {
      console.log(`Fetching more files ${s3Items.Contents[999].Key}`);
      listS3Objects(s3Items.Contents[999].Key)
    } else {
        console.log("====>",items)
    }
  });
};
```

the output of items is [01-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz]
but I want to get [01-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz, 02-data-dict-2021-04-01.gz and so on........]

Comment: [Node.js & Amazon S3: How to iterate through all files in a bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437581/node-js-amazon-s3-how-to-iterate-through-all-files-in-a-bucket)